# Sort HTML table ignoring articles ("a," "an" "the") just using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I put together an HTML table of books that I need sort ignoring "a," "an," and "the." I also need to ignore non-alphanumeric characters like quotation marks (like if the title is something like [ "Boo": A Collection of Horror Stories ]).

I've found some examples of how to sort out articles from strings. But my table data is hard-coded into the HTML. And for context, I'm working within a CMS and can't use JSON or JQUERY.

Here's the snippet.

```html
<style>
table.sash-table {
}

table.sash-table th {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}

table.sash-table th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

table.sash-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

  
table.sash-table th:hover {
color:lightgray;
}

</style>

<script>
function sortTable(n) {
const closestTable = event.target.closest("table");
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById(closestTable.id);
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

    
</script>
<html>
<table id="table-1906-1988" class="sash-table">
    <tbody style="height: 500px; display: block; overflow-y: auto;">
        <tr>
            <th class="year" onclick="sortTable(0)">Year</th>
            <th class="title" onclick="sortTable(1)">Title</th>
            <th class="authors" onclick="sortTable(2)">Author(s)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1906</td>
            <td>Salt Glazed Stoneware Germany, Flanders, England and the United States</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1906</td>
            <td>Tin Enameled Potter: Maiolica, Delft and Other Stanniferous Faience</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1907</td>
            <td>Lead glazed pottery, part first (common clays) plain glazed, sgraffito and slip-decorated wares</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1907</td>
            <td>Artificial Soft Paste Porcelain: France, Italy, Spain and England</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>

    
        <tr>
            <td>1908</td>
            <td>The Maiolica of Mexico</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1910</td>
            <td>Hard Paste Porcelain (Oriental): China, Japan, Siam, Korea</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1913</td>
            <td>Catalogue of a collection of paintings and some art objects (John G. Johnson Collection - Vol. I-III)</td>
            <td>Johnson, John Graver</td>

        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1913</td>
            <td>The W.P. Wilstach Collection</td>
            <td>Bye, Arthur Edwin</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Not exactly related, but reordering rows in a HTML table is extremely slow. You'd get this done much faster, if you'd recreate the table. If there ever won't be more than a couple of tens of rows at maximum, then you can ignore the performance issue.

Comment: Thanks! Because of character limits, the table only has about 100 rows, and sort speed is more than acceptable for my work's needs. It's a dataset of about ~200 books, so I'm using two tables, presented in a way that works nicely using the layout conventions in our CMS. And I'll only need to add about 5 rows/year.

Comment: Well then before sorting strip data you dont want, and then sort based on that. You are compering innerHTML's, well dont, save them, strip data, and compare data.

Comment: I hear you! But I need to display the books' titles as published.

Comment: Please create [mre], there is <> button in editor to create snippet. It would very much increase chances of you getting an anwser when we could test the snippet. Its hard from js code alone to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const removedString = string.replace(/^(a|an|the)(\s)/i, '');
```

This removes any a, an, the at the beginning of the string.

Edit this part of your code

```
/* Get the two elements you want to compare,
   one from current row and one from the next: */
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

/* Check if the two rows should switch place,
  based on the direction, asc or desc: */
const xValue = x.innerHTML.replace(/^(a|an|the)(\s)/i, '').toLowerCase();
const yValue = y.innerHTML.replace(/^(a|an|the)(\s)/i, '').toLowerCase();

  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (xValue > yValue) {
      // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch = true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (xValue < yValue) {
      // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

```html
<style>
table.sash-table {
}

table.sash-table th {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}

table.sash-table th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

table.sash-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

table.sash-table .year {
    width:5%;
}
  
  }
table.sash-table .authors {
  width:17.5%;
}

table.sash-table .title {
  width:38.5%;
}
 
table.sash-table .catalog {
width:12.5%;
}

table.sash-table .fulltext {
width:13.5%;
}

table.sash-table .genre {
width:12.5%;
}

table.sash-table th:hover {
color:lightgray;
}

</style>

<script>
function sortTable(n) {
const closestTable = event.target.closest("table");
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById(closestTable.id);
  switching = true;
  // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc";
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // Start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      const xValue = x.innerHTML.replace(/^(a|an|the)(\s)/i, '').toLowerCase();
      const yValue = y.innerHTML.replace(/^(a|an|the)(\s)/i, '').toLowerCase();
  
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (xValue > yValue) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (xValue < yValue) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done: */
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;
    } else {
      /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

    
</script>
<html>
<table id="table-1906-1988" class="sash-table">
    <tbody style="height: 500px; display: block; overflow-y: auto;">
        <tr>
            <th class="year" onclick="sortTable(0)">Year</th>
            <th class="title" onclick="sortTable(1)">Title</th>
            <th class="authors" onclick="sortTable(2)">Author(s)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1906</td>
            <td>Salt Glazed Stoneware Germany, Flanders, England and the United States</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1906</td>
            <td>Tin Enameled Potter: Maiolica, Delft and Other Stanniferous Faience</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1907</td>
            <td>Lead glazed pottery, part first (common clays) plain glazed, sgraffito and slip-decorated wares</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1907</td>
            <td>Artificial Soft Paste Porcelain: France, Italy, Spain and England</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>

    
        <tr>
            <td>1908</td>
            <td>The Maiolica of Mexico</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1910</td>
            <td>Hard Paste Porcelain (Oriental): China, Japan, Siam, Korea</td>
            <td>Barber, Edwin Atlee</td>
        
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1913</td>
            <td>Catalogue of a collection of paintings and some art objects (John G. Johnson Collection - Vol. I-III)</td>
            <td>Johnson, John Graver</td>

        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td>1913</td>
            <td>The W.P. Wilstach Collection</td>
            <td>Bye, Arthur Edwin</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Wow! Perfect! Thank you so much, @Doppio!